Is it true that $\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 1} \frac{c_t^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma} = \ln(c_t)$
I can't see how the  $\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 1} \frac{c_t^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma} = \ln(c_t)$
I've plotted $\frac{c^{1-g}}{1-g}$ with $g=0.9$ below and as $g \rightarrow 1$, it is clear that this limit is not true (see plot below).

The book states:

ChatGPT also seems to confirm (I probably lost you at ChatGPT):

I myself am pretty sure the correct function is (as plotted below):
$\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 1} \frac{c_t^{1-\gamma}-1}{1-\gamma} = \ln(c_t)$

Am I not seeing something?

You are correct : the problem is $\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 1} \frac{c_t^{1-\gamma}-1}{1-\gamma}$. So, (+1) for finding one (more) typo in a textbook

@s5s Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

@s5s And please feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)

The utility function is defined for $\gamma=1$. You are right that in this form we cannot see what the function is if $\gamma=1$. So we can apply the L´hôspital´s rule.
Let $f(\gamma)=c_t^{1-\gamma}-1$ and $g(\gamma)=1-\gamma$. Then we calculate the derivatives.

$f'(\gamma)= -c_t^{1 - \gamma}\cdot  \log(c_t)$

$g'(\gamma)=-1$


$$\lim_{\gamma\to 1} \frac{f'(\gamma)}{g'(\gamma)}=\lim_{\gamma\to 1} \frac{-c_t^{1 - \gamma}\cdot  \log(c_t)}{-1}$$ $$=\lim_{\gamma\to 1} c_t^{1 - \gamma} \log(c_t)=\log(c_t)$$

How is this different from my posted solution, two days earlier??

It is without base e.

That difference is immaterial.

HINT:
You are correct.
Note that $c_t^{1-\gamma}=e^{(1-\gamma)\log(c_t)}$. Thus, we can write
$$\frac{c_t^{1-\gamma}-1}{1-\gamma}=\frac{e^{(1-\gamma)\log(c_t)}-1}{1-\gamma}$$
Now, apply L'Hopital's rule.  Can you finish?

Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can

@s5s And please feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)
